# Icon Button in React Material Card

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to put the edit icon button on the right part of my card. I want to achieve like the picture below. Pls see this sandbox link for my current output

[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE LINK](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/31/d8/68/31d8689f5a7c5d75726536e2878c3edd.jpg)

[CLICK HERE FOR SANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7di2c?file=/demo.js)

```
    <CardHeader
          classes={{
            title: classes.title
          }}
          className={classes.cardHeader}
          title={"John Smith"}
          subheader={
            <h2 style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>
              User
            </h2>
          }
        />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          className={classes.editButton}
          startIcon={<EditIcon />}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ghtlj?file=/demo.js

I moved the button to the Card-content and set absolute position for it. Then the parent is relatively positioned with few styles.